# printf a double variable with asterisk (a pointer)

Tags: c, webots

I have this program in webots where I am extracting the color instance from the Wbcamerarecongnition and trying to print the color which according to documentation is made of 3D array for each color.
below is link to the documentation

I am trying to execute the following

```
const WbCameraRecognitionObject objects;
printf(" %f ", objects.color);
```

however the code crashes when i do so. any advice I want to access the color of the construct WbCameraRecognitionObject.

Comment: the link to documentation https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/camera?tab-language=c

Comment: There's no `color` member in `WbCameraRecognitionObject`. There's a pointer named `colors`.

Comment: If the compiler gave you an error message and stopping compiling, say that. Do not describe it as “the code crashes.” When an executing program gets a fatal error and is terminated by the operating system or by the hardware, that is a crash. When a compiler detects an error in a program and chooses to stop compiling because that is how the compiler is designed, that is normal and proper behavior for the compiler and is not a crash.

Answer (score 2):

`color` should be `colors`. But this is a pointer to an array of doubles, not a single value, so you need to index it. `number_of_colors` contains the size of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.number_of_colors; i++) {
    printf(" %f ", objects.colors[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```